# There is not a single rule anywhere that states asking for sources is forbidden

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

I have a question about my Stack Overflow post: [Gameboy advance assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62737661/gameboy-advance-assembly)

I have read the how to ask page, the code of conduct and even the faq, but couldn't find any single rule that states asking for a source, rater than a direct answer is forbidden.

This was the message:

We don’t allow questions seeking recommendations for books, tools, software libraries, and more. Edit the question so it can be answered with facts and citations. You can edit the question or post a new one.

Can someone please point me to the page which this rule is stated? Thanks.

Comment: Have you seen: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic ?

Comment: It's in https://stackoverflow.com/tour too

Comment: While questions asking to locate an external resource *are*, in fact, off-topic for Stack Overflow (a fact that is clearly spelled out in multiple places, as noted in the comments here), I don't actually think your question is problematic on those grounds. I've modified the wording in hopes of clarifying that you aren't seeking a *recommendation*, but simply general information about how code can be assembled for the CPU in a Game Boy Advance, and then re-opened the question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Can someone please point me to the page which this rule is stated?

Sure. It is found on [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) under the heading *Some questions are still off-topic, even if they fit into one of the categories listed above:*:

> Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Also in the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) it says under *don't ask about*

- Product or service recommendations or comparisons

So that is two places where the rule is stated.

See also [Why are “shopping list” questions bad?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158809/why-are-shopping-list-questions-bad) on the Uber Meta.

---

For your specific question on SO:

A quick search on the [network wide search](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=ARM7TDMI+) returned me [this post](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/8339/differences-between-normal-arm7tdmi-and-arm7tdmi-used-in-gba) on Retro Computing. That one is also closed for being off-topic but its answers seem to contain useful links to resources you might be looking for.

It might in this case be worth to also link you to this meta post: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)